# XML-RPC wp.getComments filter by author?

Tags: php, wordpress, xml-rpc

I would like to use Wordpress' XML-RPC to retrieve all comments associated with a particular author email, but there doesn't seem to be such a filter in the wp.getComments XML-RPC API? I wanted to check if there was a good way to do this *before* I write a plugin for it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the end I did write a plugin for it.  It required that use Wordpress' database functions directly.  Here is the extracted code for anyone else who needs to do this.  Enjoy :)

```
function catsynth_getCommentsByEmail( $args ) {
  global $wp_xmlrpc_server;
  global $wpdb;

  $wp_xmlrpc_server->escape( $args );

  $blog_id  = $args[0];
  $username = $args[1];
  $password = $args[2];
  $params   = $args[3];

  if ( ! $user = $wp_xmlrpc_server->login( $username, $password ) )
    return $wp_xmlrpc_server->error;

  $email = $params["email"];

  $query = "SELECT * FROM `wp_comments` WHERE `comment_author_email` = '".$email."' AND `comment_approved`=1 ORDER BY comment_date DESC LIMIT 0,30";

  $comments = $wpdb->get_results($query);

  foreach( $comments as $comment ) {
     $comment->post_id = $comment->comment_post_ID;
     $comment->post_title = get_the_title($comment->comment_post_ID);
  }

  return $comments;

}
```